# Using serverless framework, how to setup a Azure CosmosDB in yml file?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, serverless-framework

Using serverless.js framework, how to setup a Azure CosmosDB by setting settings in the serverless.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking with some microsoft guys,Right now there  is No specific integration with serverless.yml and Cosmos DB. You'd need to use a custom ARM template to make that happen.

Comment: It's quite difficult to get started with serverless and azure. I wish Microsoft would help out

Comment: Surely there will be an option soon

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am making a multicloud API for aws and azure, I have made aws lambda functions and added dynamodb, but I couldn't find a way to use cosmos DB or access to cosmos DB. is there a way to connect the azure functions with cosmos db and if so can you give some reference?

Comment: you can use the SQL API account with azure functions

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am using SQL api account, I added  a trigger event for the azure function in the yml file as specified in the docs [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/events/cosmosdb) and deployed it, but the function is not getting triggered for any changes in Sql table, I have tried putting the connectionString directly in yml as well tried declaring it in environments. Both didn't work

Comment: @Sajeetharan I created one more trigger function for cosmos with ui, it works fine. The `function.json` file are almost similar for both (through Serverless and portal) the functions . The function which is deployed through Serverless has these extra properties called `disabled :false` , `entryPoint:xxxx` and `scriptFile:xxxx`